# No poller has been defined for endpoint outbound adapter

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I am getting this error

"No poller has been defined for endpoint 'importExchangesOutboundAdapter'". Below is my configuration for Spring batch remote chunking.

I am using spring integration amqp.

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
    port="${rabbitmq.port}" host="${rabbitmq.host}" username="${rabbitmq.username}"
    password="${rabbitmq.password}" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory">
</rabbit:template>

<rabbit:queue name="${import.exchanges.queue}" />
<rabbit:queue name="${import.exchanges.reply.queue}" />

<int:channel id="importExchangesChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>


<int:channel id="importExchangesReplyChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>


<beans:bean id="importExchangesMessagingTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate"
    p:defaultChannel-ref="importExchangesChannel" p:receiveTimeout="${import.exchanges.reply.timeout}">
</beans:bean>

<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter id="importExchangesOutboundAdapter"
    channel="importExchangesChannel" />

<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="importExchangesInboundAdapter"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" channel="importExchangesReplyChannel"
    queue-names="${import.exchanges.reply.queue}" />


<beans:bean id="importExchangesChunkItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter"
    scope="step" p:messagingOperations-ref="importExchangesMessagingTemplate"
    p:replyChannel-ref="importExchangesReplyChannel">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="importExchangesChunkHandler"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.RemoteChunkHandlerFactoryBean"
    p:chunkWriter-ref="importExchangesChunkItemWriter" p:step-ref="importExchangesStep">
</beans:bean>

<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="importExchangesSlaveInboundAdapter"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" channel="${import.exchanges.queue}Channel"
    queue-names="${import.exchanges.queue}" />



<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter id="importExchangesSlaveOutboundAdapter"
    channel="importExchangesReplyChannel" />

<int:service-activator id="serviceActivatorExchanges"
    input-channel="importExchangesChannel" output-channel="importExchangesReplyChannel"
    ref="chunkProcessorChunkHandlerExchanges" method="handleChunk" />

<beans:bean id="chunkProcessorExchanges"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor"
    p:itemWriter-ref="importExchangesItemWriter" />

<beans:bean id="chunkProcessorChunkHandlerExchanges"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkProcessorChunkHandler"
    p:chunkProcessor-ref="chunkProcessorExchanges" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your defined endpoint `importExchangesOutboundAdapter` that has channel `importExchangesChannel` to poll messages from because the channel is a `Queue` channel which requires a poller to be configured for message consumption.

Simple answer is to define a global poller like below:

```
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="100"/>
```

Comment: <int:channel id="importExchangesChannel" /> channel definition doesn't have queue. sorry didnt get what you mean by "channel is queue"

Comment: Yes, it does. You can remove the `<int:queue/>` child element from that channel, or add a poller to the outbound adapter (or define a global poller as Rajesh suggested). But you generally don't need to queue outbound requests, so just removing the child element is simplest.